# NetSuite Create Purchase Order Workflow without Sales Order

Tags: workflow, netsuite, purchase-order

In NetSuite, is there a setting which limits Purchase Orders (OP) being applicable to a Workflow (WF) based on a Sales Order (SO) transformation vs stand alone PO?

Have a workflow on PO creation which sets a field value and this works perfectly when this is created by originating from a SO line item. When creating a stand alone PO the workflow does not trigger and there is no log of it even evaluating whether to perform the WF actions at all.

```
Record Type: Transaction

Sub Type: Purchase Order

Initiation: Event Based

On Create: checked

Trigger Type: Before Record Load

Event Type: Create

Contexts: 
 * Client
 * Portlet
 * Restlet
 * Scheduled Script
 * Suitelet
 * User Event Script
 * User Interface
 * Web Services, Workflow
```

Comment: You need to put some information on how you set your workflow(like Trigger Type, Event Type, Context)

Comment: @vVinceth Updated to include these things